# How to disable ognl evaluation?

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

To force OGNL evaluation one could use the %{} syntax, but what should be used to disable it?

Consider following code -

```
<s:a action="likeButton">
   <s:param name="returnAction" value="viewItem" />
</s:a>
```

What happens is that viewItem is looked up on the value stack and when it isn't found an empty string gets returned.

```
likeButton?returnAction=
```

This is not what I want. What I wanted was the literal value viewItem to be passed as a parameter.

```
likeButton?returnAction=viewItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delimiter your literal with single quotes inside the double quotes and then it should be fine.

```
<s:a action="likeButton">    
    <s:param name="returnAction" value="'viewItem'" /> 
</s:a>
```

Regards,